# Python doesn't accept my input, what I'm I doing wrong?

Tags: python, input

I'm creating code for the mastermind game and I think that everything should be perfect, but when I try to write the info needed by the first input (in this case, the colors like "R", it doesn't matter what I do that will jump directly to 
print ("You have to introduce four colours, no more, no less! ")

Can anyone help me please???

Here's the code:

```
colours=["R", "G", "B", "Y", "W", "R", "P"]
attempts=0
game=True


codemaker=random.sample(colours,4)
print (codemaker)

while game:
    white_points=0
    black_points=0
    guessed_colour=""
    player_guess=input().upper()
    attempts+=1

    if len(player_guess) != len(codemaker):
        print ("You have to introduce four colours, no more, no less! ")
        continue
```

Comment: What exactly are you inputing into `input`? Are you only inputting a single letter?

Comment: I could not reproduce the error. I suspect your input is faulty.

Comment: the result of `input` is a string. From your code, your input must be a string of 4 letters, e,g, `rgby` for the `len` comparison to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a little lightweight debugging with **print** and you will see that the code does exactly what you asked it to do: it doesn't print("You have to introduce four colours, no more, no less! ") when the lengths are the same  4:

```
import random

colours=["R", "G", "B", "Y", "W", "R", "P"]
attempts=0
game=True

codemaker=random.sample(colours,4)
print(len(codemaker), codemaker)

while game:
    white_points=0
    black_points=0
    guessed_colour=""
    player_guess=input().upper()
    attempts+=1
    print(player_guess, len(player_guess))

    if len(player_guess) != len(codemaker):
        print("You have to introduce four colours, no more, no less! ")
        continue
```

Testing...

```
4 ['W', 'B', 'R', 'G']
abcde
ABCDE 5
You have to introduce four colours, no more, no less! 
WBRG
WBRG 4
@#$%^U
@#$%^U 6
You have to introduce four colours, no more, no less!
```